# Is this possible to update the database in a schedule using php?

Tags: php, database

For example, I got a table like this:

`Activities:
id
start_time
status`

And I would like to insert an activity, start in `2013-01-01`, `status` is `0`,
if the server become `2013-01-01`, the `status` will become `1`.

I can write a simple scheduler a `java` programme to execute a `schedule` action, when the `php` programme is submit to the database. Also, I can have a long polling `php` programme to check so. Also, I can have a database trigger to do so. I can also check if there any any records need to execute which time the user called.....

But is there anyway

```
1. to use php ONLY, no database trigger is prefered.
2. the schedule can content can be editable easier. 
3. no need the client to driven the change status execution, if no body is calling the requested .php, status can also changed in database, it changed based on time, not by event
```

For example of point 2, I may have a table that store after execute status, for example, it can change to status to `3`, instead of `1`. The table is something like this:

`Activity_executes: id activities_id change_status_code`

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script in PHP to check up on events, and update as needed.  You could then call it with a cron job on a schedule that you set.  You'd still be able to run the same script manually if you choose or need to.